# What HTTP method do I use to retrieve information when also requiring a one-time passcode?

Tags: api, rest, http

I have done some research regarding this, but I haven't found a solid answer for this particular situation.

Let's say I have a route called `/information` that returns some sensitive data of a specified `info_id` and only if provided with a valid `one_time_code`.

I can think to do this in two ways:

1. GET /information?info_id=x&one_time_code=y
2. POST /information
   body: *info_id* = x, *one_time_code* = y

Response (this does not change, nor does anything else in the database - the one time code has an expiry - and can be cleared via a different way):

```json
{
    "info_owner_id" : "1234",
    ...
}
```

From how I understand it the GET approach would seem to be the more RESTful approach, but may not be ideal as the URL with the query strings would get saved in the browser and perhaps results would get cached along the way. Also, the `info_id` could leak along the way (even if using HTTPS as its in the URL).

However, with the POST approach, nothing is cached and expired codes won't be saved in the browser. However, nothing is created and in fact, the database isn't altered at all so it may not be the most 'logical' approach.

I'm struggling to understand what would be the best practices in this situation, I hope to receive some clarification.

Furthermore, if you think a completely different way is preferable, please let me know. I was thinking to use GET with authentication headers, but my site doesn't have 'users' in its database, but people can save their own info and get access to it with generated links (info_id / one time code sent via email).

Comment: `Authorization` header?

Comment: @Evert thanks for the comment. I don't really have users but I guess the info_id@one_time_code combo can be considered as credentials to be used as Basic auth.

Though I may need to send a captcha-response too, which will be verified in my backend. Should I use custom headers for One-Time-Code and Captcha-Response instead, would that be a better practice?

Comment: Authorization doesn't imply 'user', it just a way to send secret tokens that grant a client access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTful API often use GET (read), POST (create), PUT (replace/update) and DELETE (to delete a record).

So with your case, people often use get method.

GET /information/{infoId}

With sensitive information, I highly recommend we should hide it anyway, hide it from the eye of user.

So in my opinion, we should put one-time token code in header if you use get, or put it in body if you use post method.

Even if with https, get or post are both secure. I still want to keep it hidden from the eye of user.

Stateless is ideal, but it's hard to reach when the system is quite complex with authentication, timeout, one-time token, ....

Comment: Thanks, I think the GET method with the code in the header sounds ideal for this situation. I'll probably do that after just making sure with additional research

Answer (score 1):

If the one time code leaks, is it a problem as it can be used only once? I mean even if you send it on the url, the response will be retrieved and if the hacker wants to reuse it, it won't work...

And in my opinion the most RESTful way would be:

`GET /information/{infoId}?oneTimeCode=xxx`

or

`GET /information/{infoId}/{oneTimeCode}`

But it's not really RESTful as it is not stateless, providing you cannot access the same resource twice with the same url.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely correct, this does seem to be more appropriate - the 1st one particularly I think.

Could I perhaps instead include the `One-Time-Code` as a HTTP header? Would that be a bad practice? Also, may need to add a Google reCaptcha response code in a similar way on the same route.

Comment: Indeed sending the one time code in the header could be a good practise too. If you feel the answer was good, do not hesitate to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a GET request. Even if the request was cached in the browser history (I'd use XHR/ajax), getting the one-time code isn't a destructive action and wouldn't really be a danger. As you've mentioned, since nothing is being altered, you should go with a GET request. P.S, All query GET parameters are as secure as the POST body would be with SSL.